# How to add background image for widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Trying to add background image for widget in flutter app but i do not know how to add it. I am new for flutter.So, If Anyone knows please help to find the solutions.

login.dart:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold( 
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 1,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Image.asset("images/logo.png"),
          ),
        
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          TextField(
            .........
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          TextField(
            ..........
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          TextField(
            ..........
          ) 
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the SingleChildScrollView with a Container and add decoration

```dart
Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
 body: Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     image : DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('imagePathHere'),
     )
   ),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(

    )
 )
)
```

Comment: Not able to access the text field

Comment: I didn't understand. Not able to access? Aren't you able to scroll to that part?

Comment: Edited my answer. Add height and width for the container

Comment: Now,After onfocus on text field the background image size also resizing

Comment: Use resizeToAvoidBottomInset and set it to false in scaffold

Comment: What is the correct size of background image for mobile?

Comment: Bcoz in my app 660X1350 like this image only working. Is it correct?

Comment: We added height and width same as the screen size by using MediaQuery

Comment: To fit the screen. You can use fit: BoxFit.contain

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/background_image.jpg'), 
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello, Flutter!',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```